# How can I edit the details (e.g. change the email address) of a recipient in my Transferwise's account?

Tags: untagged

How can I edit the details (e.g. change the email address) of a recipient in my Transferwise's account?

I can see the option on https://transferwise.com/user/recipients/list:

[image]

Comment: doesn't look like there's a way to edit

Answer (score 0):

As Sathyajith Bhat mentioned in the comments, it doesn't look like there's a way to edit. It appears the only option is to delete and recreate.